# Multiple illogical errors showing for program utilizing a function, switch statement, and multidimensional array

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I am having issues with my code that really make no sense. Certain things are being called errors at one point and not at other points. It is calling for a parenthesis but I do not see where it is even needed. The IDE is telling me I need semi colons after my function declaration before the definition but that is only needed after the prototype. The code looks solid but these errors keep popping up. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using std::istream;

int FizzBuzz(int, int);

int main()
{
    int rowNum{};                      // Declaration and initialization of     variable number
    int columnNum{};                   // Declaration and initialization of  variable number
    int counter{};                     // Declaration/initialization of counter
    int array[4][4]{ { 60, 84, 50, 57 } ,{ 80, 75, 10, 54 } ,{ 81, 33, 55, 90 } ,{ 21, 35, 63, 45 } }; 
// Array initialization/Declaration
    char indicator{ 'n' };             // Continue or not?

    cout << "Welcome to my Fizzbuzz game, you are to guess the location of a "
         << "number which if is divisible by 5 and 3 you will win with "
         << "the output of Fizzbuzz. " << endl;

    for (;;)
    {
        counter++;

        switch (!(int FizzBuzz(int, int) % 15)) {
            case 1: printf("You win you got FizzBuzz!!! \n"); 
                cout << "It took you " << counter << " tries." << endl;
                break;

            case 0:

                switch (!(int FizzBuzz(int, int) % 3)) {
                    case 1: printf("Fizz, please try again. \n"); 
                        break;

                    case 0: 

                        switch (!(int FizzBuzz(int, int) % 5)) {
                            case 1:  printf("Buzz, please try again. \n"); 
                                break;

                            case 0: printf("please enter another input. \n"); 
                                break;
            }; break;
            }; break;
        }
        cout << endl << "Do you want to enter another array (please enter y     or n? ";
        cin >> indicator;           // Read indicator
        if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
            break;                  // Exit from loop
}

    int FizzBuzz(int, int)
    {
        int result{};

        cout << "Please enter an integer value between 0 and 3 "
             << "representing the row location of the number for the game, "
             << "then press the Enter key: " << endl;

        switch (rowNum)
        {
        case 0: cout << endl
            << "Now please enter a value for the location within the column." << endl;
            cin >> columnNum;

            result = array[rowNum][columnNum]
            break;

        case 1: cout << endl 
            << "Now please enter a value for the location within the column." << endl;
            cin >> columnNum;

            result = array[rowNum][columnNum]
            break;

        case 2: cout << endl 
            << "Now please enter a value for the location within the column." << endl;
            cin >> columnNum;

            result = array[rowNum][columnNum]
            break;

        case 3: cout << endl 
            << "Now please enter a value for the location within the column." << endl;

            result = array[rowNum][columnNum]
            break;

        default: cout << endl << "You entered an incorrect value."
            << endl;

            result = 0;
            break;
        }
        return result;
```

Again I really do not understand where the issues are as I have even had help writing this.

Comment: Start at the top. Place the cursor on/behind a brace, and check if the corresponding closing brace is highlighted. Or deactivate code blocks using #ifdef/#endif clauses until it compiles, then start re-adding parts of code, solve compiler errors, repeat.

Comment: Corresponding braces are being highlighted. I am not sure what you mean by using #ifdef/#endif clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many bugs in your code. I suggest turning on the compiler warnings and analyzing both warnings and error messages.

In multiple places in `main` you have for some `intLiteral`:

```
int FizzBuzz(int, int) % intLiteral
```

This is not how you call a function. You should probably use something like

```
FizzBuzz(rowNum, columnNum) % intLiteral
```

instead. Also note that you're switching on boolean values (e.g. `!(FizzBuzz(42, 42) % 3)`) and compare it to integers `0` and `1` (e.g. `case 0:`). Why not use an `if` statement instead?

The definition of `main` is missing a closing `}` before the declaration of `FizzBuzz`.

The definition of `FizzBuzz` is also missing a closing `}`, and is also missing names for its parameters. The definition should probably start as

```
int FizzBuzz(int rowNum, int columnNum)
{
```

The variable `array` should also probably be part of `FizzBuzz` instead of `main`.

The lines `result = array[rowNum][columnNum]` in `FizzBuzz` are missing semicolons at the end.

Comment: I have updated the expression as switch (!(FizzBuzz(array, rowNum) % 5)) but it shows array as an error. I fixed the bracket but it still shows erroneous braces. It also shows errors in both switches.

Comment: Having the switch statement is a requirement.

Comment: @phoenixCoder Edited my answer